# Canvas in WPF takes too much memory when rendering an image

Tags: wpf, image, canvas, memory, draw

I'm displaying images on WPF Canvas, it works fine but it uses 3 times of memory as I expected. Is this the way WPF supposed to work or I'm doing something wrong?

I wrote all in the comments. Basically the image itself takes 40m but WPF takes 120M of memory to display on the canvas. It's really easy to recreate.

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="1000" Height="1000"/>
    </Grid>
```

CS:

```
            Image image = new Image();    
        
            // The following writeableBitmap takes 40M memory, it makes sense as it equals to width * height * 4 bytes/pixel (1000*10000*4). In this demo I just added this to blank map to the canvas. 
            var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(1000, 10000, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);
           // it takes 80M memory if you don't freeze it. 
            writeableBitmap.Freeze(); 

            image.Source = writeableBitmap;

            // The following single line takes 80M. So with writeableBitmap it takes 120M in total to display an 40M image. 
            canvas.Children.Add(image);//80M
```

I googled but couldn't find a clue.  I used DrawingVisual to draw the image and the results are the same.

Thanks in advance!

Ben

Comment: Why are you using a WriteableBitmap? You can create a BitmapSource directly from a byte array.

Comment: what is the expected behavior? have you benchmarked it with other controls, other types of bitmaps and other pixel formats?

Comment: @Clemens. It's the same case for BitmapSource. It takes 40M itself, but takes 80M when adding it to the canvas. I feel something wrong in the Canvas.

Comment: @Bizhan, the sample code was simplified to make sure everyone can easily recreated it without any dependencies. I tried BitmapImage and it is the same case. I expect it only takes 40M of memory instead of 120M, as the image itself only takes 40M.

Comment: It's not the Canvas, but the Image element.

Comment: @Clemens In that case any idea where I'm doing wrong? The code is as simple as possible.

Comment: @BenBai You aren't doing anything wrong. I don't know the details about how exactly the Image element renders a bitmap, but there is nothing wrong in your code.

Comment: So your question is "why" writeableBitmap takes more memory than bitmap. I can guess because it does more than bitmap probably...

Comment: @Bizhan. I think that writeableBitMap is fine, it takes 40M of memory which makes sense. My question is why it takes 80M more memory after adding it to a canvas, that seems not making sense.

Comment: @Clemens, Not sure if there's a better way to display an image.  Isn't using the image element the most straightforward way? I tried DrawingVisual and it's the same regarding the memory.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=netcore-3.1#remarks